# How do I answer these financial questions on UK visa form?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, online-resources, standard-visitor-visas

I am being sponsored by my father and he will pay the full cost of my trip. He will pay 6000 towards a trip that will cost 3000. How do I answer the following questions:

1- What is the cost to you personally of your trip in GBP(£)?

2- The total amount of money you have for this trip? (Is this the money I have, or just the amount given to me?????)
After this question it asks about individual cost of plane tickets, accomadation and living expenses.

Then It asks 'Is someone other than you paying for all or a part of your trip?' where I stated my father will pay, and i placed the amount he will pay as 6000. After the amount he will pay and why he will pay questions there is another weird question asking:

3- 'What is the total amount in GBP(£)?(What is the total cost of your trip, including money others may be giving you, in GBP(£)') I honestly dont understand this one

Here is an image of what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcYCe.jpg

Comment: Is this the official website? I filled a UK application recently (two months ago) and it was so different (even the design). I was sponsoring someone and I filled the application and the questions were totally different..

Comment: This is the older site, the new site currently glitches for me on the pay option; this is what i see: https://i.imgur.com/ICYjwxA.png

Comment: yes, that's the new site, and it was working fine for me.

Comment: What windows and browser did you use?
I'm using windows10 and latest version of chrome. I am beginning to suspect that the issue is with my windows or browser.

Comment: I am using windows 10 + Edge..